# Simple tool with chat notifications for integration with a wiki and Kanban tool

Tags: chat, wiki

I look for a way to integrate a chat like Mattermost or Rocket chat with a wiki like DokuWiki and a simple Kanban tool like Trello or Asane.

I don't want something software developpement oriented (no Scrum, no user stories, no repository).

Taiga for example is too much developper oriented, like open project.